# validate and transform a field value using ajv in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, serialization, ajv

I want to validate and change field `json_data.childOrder.Order.triggerPrice` using ajv. But my customKeyword function is never called.

I want to update it to 10% of `json_data.ltp`

I tried to read the documentation but its not very clear how to do this. And moany examples on stackoverflow are referring to old version of `ajv` library.

```
const Ajv = require('ajv')
const ajv = new Ajv({ coerceTypes: true }) // options can be passed, e.g. {allErrors: true}

const OrderSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        childOrder: {
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: true,
            properties: {
                Order: {
                    type: 'object',

                    additionalProperties: true,

                    properties: {
                        qty: {
                            type: 'string'
                        },
                        triggerPrice: {
                            type: 'number'
                        }

                    },
                    required: ['triggerPrice', 'qty']

                }

            }
        }

    },
    additionalProperties: true

}

json_data = {
    childOrder: {
        Order: {
            buy: 'true',
            orderType: '3',
            price: 3999,
            qty: '10',
            triggerPrice: 3400
        }
    },
    duration: 'DAY',
    ltp: 3435,
    orderType: '3',
    price: 0,
    product: 'wood',
    qty: '10',
}

ajv.addKeyword({
    keyword: 'triggerPrice',
    type: 'number',
    compile: (a, b) => {
        // logic to transaform trigger price
        console.log(a, b)
    }
})
const validateOrder = ajv.compile(OrderSchema)

const _validate = validateOrder(json_data)
```

are there any other alternate ways of doing validatin in nodejs like there are in python marshmallow and django DRF.